# Jquery - var not being updated on resize, but being saved multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created this piece of jquery-script with the purpose of enabling/disabling a div having position:fixed based on how far the user has scrolled (it's basically a combination of scripts that others have made, which i have adopted - so credit to them). It is working intentionally at first, but upon resizing the window, it breaks. I've come to the conclusion that the error lies in the old variables not being updated correctly upon resizing, even though I've tried to do so. I've searched quite a lot for an answer, but haven't been able to.

I have made some console.log's to find the error, and what i found is that: 
When I load the page it works fine - however, when i resize the window, the function "indholdScroll" gets kind of duplicated when scrolling. When scrolling, the variable "containerOffsetTop" is called 2 times (2 calls if resized 1 time, and gets called even more times if you have resized more times). In the first call the variable has the initial value (from page load) and in the second call, it has the value of the new size, based on the window-resize.

So, the problem is that:

1. The old values of the variable isn't replaced (specifically of the variable "containerOffsetTop", which is causing me the trouble)
2. The function/variable "indholdScroll" is called multiple times, based on how many times the window has been resized.

I've really tried to find a solution for this, but without any luck. Therefore i'm asking you guys, if you could help me.

This is my script (jsfiddle if someone wants to "play" with it, and the code it self):
https://jsfiddle.net/4got971s/5/

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("katalog") === -1) && (window.location.href.indexOf("detail") > -1)) {
        var indholdScroll;
        indholdScroll = function() {
            var plHeight = jQuery("#PL-container").innerHeight();
            if (window.innerWidth > 560 && jQuery(window).innerHeight() > 590) {
                jQuery(".indhold-container").css("height", plHeight);
            } else {
                jQuery(".indhold-container").css("height", "auto");
            };
            var windw = this;
            var indholdDivHeight = jQuery(".indhold-inner").outerHeight(true);
            var indholdTop = parseInt(jQuery(".indhold-inner").css('top'), 10);
            var mainPadding = parseInt(jQuery("#main").css("paddingTop"), 10);
            var entryHeaderHeight = jQuery(".entry-header").outerHeight(true);
            var indholdHeight = jQuery(".entry-footer").offset().top - indholdTop - indholdDivHeight;
            var thresholdCrossed = false;
            var thresholdCrossedTop = false;

            var containerOffsetTop = jQuery("#PL-container").offset().top;

            jQuery.fn.followTo = function(pos) {
                var $this = this,
                    $window = jQuery(windw);

                jQuery(window).scroll(function(e) {
                    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

                    //console.log for testing purpose
                    console.log("scroll: " + scroll);
                    console.log("scroll containeroffsetTop: " + containerOffsetTop);
                    console.log(scroll >= containerOffsetTop);

                    jQuery(function() {
                        if (!thresholdCrossedTop && scroll >= containerOffsetTop) {
                            $this.addClass("fixedscroll");
                        } else if (!thresholdCrossed && scroll >= pos) {
                            $this.removeClass("fixedscroll");
                            $this.addClass("posibot");
                        } else if (thresholdCrossed && scroll <= pos) {
                            $this.removeClass("posibot");
                            $this.addClass("fixedscroll");
                        } else if (thresholdCrossedTop && scroll <= containerOffsetTop) {
                            $this.removeClass("fixedscroll");
                        };
                    });
                    thresholdCrossed = scroll > pos;
                    thresholdCrossedTop = scroll > containerOffsetTop;
                });
            };

            jQuery('.indhold-inner').followTo(indholdHeight);

        };
        indholdScroll();
        var timeOutResize;
        jQuery(window).resize(function() {
            clearTimeout(timeOutResize);
            timeOutResize = setTimeout(function() {
                indholdScroll();
            }, 500);
        });
    };
});
```

EDIT:
I have updated the fiddle to include HTML - the link over the code is now correct. Do note that i had to change the script a bit, to make it work at jsfiddle - as an example from "$(window).scroll" to "$("#page").scroll".

EDIT 2: 
Note that the "div" in question is ".indhold-inner" and can be found out at the right of the page with a slight grey background and the text saying "spring til overskrift".

EDIT 3:

Solution so far: 
As @skobaljic answered, I had included `fn.followTo` definition and call of the function, inside the function `indholdScroll()` function which are called upon resize to update the variables. However, separating the functions required that i made the variables global (i think?) which i'm not sure is the best solution? The updated script (and solution so far) can be found here, and seems to be working as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/4got971s/13/

Comment: nice fiddle! can't see the html :|

Comment: Actually didn't include any HTML, as I thought it would be enough for someone more experienced than my self, to see the error in just the script :) My bad!
I can link to the current homepage with the problems though - however i'm not sure if that's accepted?

Comment: uh..just add as much html as necessary. i guess the header is causing problem, right? just add that in the html box of jsfiddle(with css of course). we can't solve a problem until we can reproduce it(most of the time).

Comment: The fiddle has now been updated with HTML - PLEASE NOTE that you might have to zoom out, for the script to work (i have NO idea why :) - and please dont mind the CSS.. i've just copied all the css in, to save some time). 
The link is now: https://jsfiddle.net/4got971s/5/ 

I have updated the original post as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `jQuery('.indhold-inner').followTo(indholdHeight);` inside the `indholdScroll` function, which each time sets new `jQuery(window).scroll` event. Also, `jQuery.fn.followTo` should be defined outside of `indholdScroll` function.

Comment: You are right! But putting `jQuery('.indhold-inner').followTo(indholdHeight); ` and the definition of `jQuery.fn.followTo` outside also means that i'm setting them out of scope - so is there an easier/more correct way to define the variables, other than stating them outside the `indholdScroll` function? But thanks for telling!

Comment: Your answer actually seems to be the right one - although i'm not certain if my solution is ;) I have updated the fiddle with my new script: https://jsfiddle.net/4got971s/13/ . It's seemingly working as intended now, after i've separated the functions. However, i'm not quite sure whether i've done it the best way, as i've made all the variables global? Any thoughts? I'll update the question with the answer at the bottom and i've selected your answer is the correct one - thank you :)

Comment: If you worry about global vars, than just wrap your code in anonymous function `(function() { ... })();`, they will still stay in scope. Maybe you should read more about [Javascript variable scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Comment: Well actually the entire script is inside a `.on("load", function() { ... }):` however without defining the variables as in the before mentioned fiddle, i'm getting errors in debugger and it doesn't work, and returns as undefined. I'm still actually getting an error on resize, saying that `indholdScroll()` has an uncaught reference error - and I have no idea why. However, redefining it as `$.fn.indholdScroll` solves this.. But yeah, maybe I should read some more about scopes ;)

Edit: surprisingly (for me) wrapping the script further in `$(function(){..` also solves the referenceerror